# Cassandra is not picking initial_token

Tags: cassandra

I am following the official documentation for procedure for [Restoring a snapshot into a new cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html#opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster). As per this,

```
4. Clear the system table data from each new node:
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*
This allows the new nodes to use the initial tokens defined in the cassandra.yaml when they restart.

5. Start each node using the specified list of token ranges in new cluster's cassandra.yaml:
initial_token: -9211270970129494930, -9138351317258731895, -8980763462514965928, ...
```

I am following these 2 steps exactly.
In fact, it is verified by cassandra debug logs.

```
INFO  [main] 2017-11-16 09:36:59,353 Config.java:456 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=cassandra-staging-restored; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=/mnt/cassandra/data/commitlog; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=null; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@43301423; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=/mnt/cassandra/data/hints; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=true; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=-9095105683159122588, -9064001015036599926, -9013000709875877114, -8829167773634478741, -8730304531409075421, -8615439886540673174, -8270623326447012978, -8176731878564157082, -8106822260307184341, -8089230042068892584, -8048906315856045311, -8028060929375944874, -7997403222481000091, -7980484429523277359, -7974470050771642191, -7851931228156318619, -7803664353182134419, -7788144370469500201, -7757626955856652301, -7712114049802319218, -7567720775920874700, -7551341429242695915, -7541865877881094180, -7514992388769119302, -7453108576041420033, -7431137934229111567, -7385697214426296194, -7326461701752475949, -7229952075030336177, -7218589485893294366, -7135605539700697459, -7062493953257887070, -6920687217081027707, -6916831669158286277, -6834053763268440089, -6822142837027528938, -6803094670398379101, -6602427539566207665, -6568182869870496307, -6511459920765505444, -6475249533685490199, -6428402884562770941, -6404676233544011759, -6360685224996369272, -6247121131610539884, -6246197555819424550, -6237368585021940017, -6153182247036415095, -6111450384148334970, -6042018771685803203, -5944793473876873149, -5863379160236916223, -5856475313797546183, -5832717016324856051, -5638468189438508210, -5539167370710819367, -5485280601523987503, -5474309089162218374, -5319174053461867928, -5300518577149097037, -5245536441075283612, -5112569688111722752, -4898240302203107111, -4881568115746221858, -4824104622873342498, -4701179017811291386, -4429755340063878775, -4413214557193145518, -4345418978114596882, -4079966796765885842, -4061762443047240866, -4030858175577795653, -4021547736638981847, -3836302740108504981, -3751768720526789019, -3743461742087956083, -3608810097734181459, -3607048178493709454, -3581158125752648978, -3562376827907111596, -3534668228830524620, -3431416556842048483, -3393885233868129949, -3339504094398301776, -3339170395338364082, -3307612236986384680, -3265920212434927166, -3204785075022793989, -3140386460827349755, -3099066887010465462, -3080689217189133335, -3007133744629835172, -2959846903344801620, -2888247723844507160, -2797992536166356195, -2712194459828626645, -2684177990525837322, -2658075701966969657, -2561917844478305786, -2492629295365129028, -2487719825222497546, -2399789247381255821, -2241309724624423586, -2108173119695457257, -2052360610564904726, -1939271054812802955, -1917043893384955146, -1808888302673267763, -1646863387940805021, -1634994825307804368, -1609712683106528653, -1300771381145801651, -1278385576576119381, -1274643898977022746, -950901630804463153, -940580146197028656, -731515730336327054, -642040964228514704, -608433393788453231, -478573951386945456, -436153095069462168, -416275106775833677, -378149959056786595, -346798880456427869, -305717523770204725, -284546652114461767, -166337978258482678, -101574744252082785, -30754271282451326, -6946162971722353, -4662052994008400, 68233019263256270, 126207333796953658, 132958619259436796, 166586855936325288, 180257471364193954, 222412061324634542, 299152219068289859, 307967555141655158, 499885456475913627, 510710569344453193, 512082871639239079, 551467999030970818, 560270740776978967, 563581994761305584, 687058605177782549, 793693682518320692, 917345500055208403, 935027642243141249, 1167582121991529631, 1177005535757550036, 1226282557885818866, 1279109759358271230, 1376609314865350358, 1388467321396881673, 1422156903349974253, 1475548349950097082, 1586261249441981681, 1594387271495404471, 1637548112971596569, 1759270488237130010, 1936016394983722984, 1991608383818464987, 2208451829114082571, 2242674193749084268, 2461080713362404466, 2539772799528407861, 2559844306686112571, 2620884963938532750, 2631650124112820870, 2664129588892760377, 2704157604972767845, 2736768902813611411, 2843328646543212128, 2856803091245137446, 2872960500638572538, 3138686478845054074, 3162031242206258542, 3185538412991024850, 3256233823832431553, 3284337403758100585, 3382411519818362465, 3490207566034869602, 3594317170903296648, 3669639735626576929, 3787200951518921417, 3805575545151951881, 3930156481299524524, 4109302677069830167, 4162318623147816383, 4174122441845031013, 4184778082562775012, 4333398546246868435, 4429402131470597299, 4454026097116561450, 4505802367873280245, 4538296977730990054, 4556607070107659214, 4570854427961759192, 4623296353148907992, 4679204413345951708, 4835621991534530902, 4873358208143831472, 4877348486234759943, 4909265243325179596, 4916889701925751547, 5050438954348872869, 5095687454372630280, 5225622553567840544, 5362122150810830638, 5453189930700137106, 5607985707233264385, 5627412929991624017, 5715642638971959215, 5792552742790972143, 5958282382337339668, 5966221173142140715, 6034708041737829912, 6035042265093059146, 6044918925766439026, 6117274929043661295, 6287231019632644302, 6317296677286381680, 6347246668613761526, 6386913449650684351, 6484548945192165912, 6809960070854586220, 7007749647532345769, 7064744556786092960, 7188015426890314535, 7381000932719845319, 7587261946507044657, 7642859702759477380, 7880162680349272441, 7908612477022491169, 7933323898613557131, 7937658449054724067, 7970141900392419694, 7979202070554210097, 7990763252197782986, 7995201022333707512, 7995792407943250493, 8140167553977835725, 8207869160118839667, 8384513993725731980, 8425627379584317458, 8450167920418959385, 8558753444678316624, 8635896206896058589, 8655999832148389735, 8749247593003798317, 8793336959659815954, 8811175299936105223, 8960172117500802825, 9082531635065196023, 9119004294127950942; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=10.120.8.116; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=1; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_coalescing_strategy=TIMEHORIZON; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=10.120.8.116; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/mnt/cassandra/data/saved_caches; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=10.120.8.233,10.120.8.213,10.120.8.116,10.120.8.29,10.120.8.251}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@2f112965; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000
```

But the initial_tokens are those which were auto-generated by cassandra when it was first started.

```
INFO  [main] 2017-11-16 05:52:57,322 StorageService.java:1030 - Generated random tokens. tokens are [-1389648523687197109, -732698274772120137, -6376639320886405616, -873424736264959023, 8595953819512872578, 6773654626092013980, 9148695480551165081, 8209470968081970646, 9110581623169741801, 8012929209487966833, 7452692620314248468, 3103266257146948503, 5679525578987403003, -4522063905876778141, -6135750996189542432, 415784996037656153, 4396058137183394429, 692447961111726586, -6531662267543500154, 245834976461441926, -3064167806548065705, 8943572903844965496, -8638802229987964486, -8160083686661602566, -3050334815467563212, -8542758292854754936, 5709282354905481607, 88986928287276648, 1373249395890303055, -1686001724516419324, -396828971815045007, -8794909476111352967, -222280635739262458, -5414806845469275848, -2054698046151951295, -3554921400589962677, -7505704101012649583, 4179877325296378655, 7507175622338132461, -3496771293631065989, -3269044636044041612, -2009963074060585591, -2105986620005447634, 5330076034215385934, -4344640060181026104, 617483922231457714, 6465679396586550255, 5268797296416377890, 8377470147983205477, -8297832552754006887, -74853680046366003, -2872441811245832825, -2916068111566416056, 8408680662553618809, -2520357715711164569, -1560036757814314210, -5257702498481345613, -1017232662177787435, -4767292845107768798, -907567868062273876, 8870536721819084448, -6581232938993081706, 3822595822833559746, -7289338527755522826, -7639859898047414864, -4037700692557190365, 5049983552065810879, -5561302251870351386, 4621684495888003169, -3131443300514015633, -1160430662405286954, -8097490517397089231, -7348298090590090758, 5509208719656812112, -6481250052576231824, -5996741154396422167, -8294729397011283217, 2995257461252438837, -4352117679133792335, 1233012258201042528, 9035122281098363653, 6405344801897697404, 8708109275467472592, 8539949944069553390, 213833451306356755, -4166035949030694285, -8970221914082044097, 4606844533012524108, 947526220642208048, -2801978367402508153, -4532865176940942027, -1594392693891556555, -5806887334100689059, -2394088246665207424, 4234652354740925563, -8076001124699026366, 8744811137913444802, 62796481248292599, 6455733404981444252, -126533974378819127, 5843584371728823073, 5445168425290460940, 6707320880322895668, 4573751191752231090, -2127663589976413582, 1954401089317717447, -5300938135871221896, 5093721835155884661, -2524179837794403109, -6385219008186858160, 7325353601705788106, -840570978863751222, 5759885770816159939, 9072054183035599574, -8308763822241266759, -2586762965601191160, -432658258571974620, 3019044186650827069, 5726665958978111481, 6052672856134820217, 7838411235214044945, 2112902061202895279, 6260813920434498398, -8658490402119023263, 2928460241999085176, -8088631625855485121, -3893350039068301015, -1883547399497783790, -4931508961242998715, 1962026677878034467, -3536945581565756993, -3980665635466622441, 1616177331508810053, 4312023170834343978, 2878951844701050184, 7237763498599271588, -4143611656813097424, -3034833307460628079, -8631680602869413810, -5149492198682224552, -2010682875598030955, 2599132540851755500, -2955657629453800874, 7849160639412118736, 4066126615292533141, 8785492290797937036, -2425804637592817359, -81469586499474786, -8457085973377633413, 7938935767281129568, 5555025259044091280, -928104310141668027, 7576407531657016973, 1924068444759082739, -714923442136005577, -7424796994965823987, -8286550103460241539, 3795917762129273051, -8178762033443435991, 199935774895264752, 7223315731747941169, 2131952788031994270, -5924194093356500134, 8312801612720650647, -3455990260940501757, -6752550707935826850, -6601973406625917854, 1003897288641305994, -2311356538255289914, 6198153789687000292, 4371280172613277105, -3103750689457909819, -4749463815536259135, -371035516354562506, -3121297865532053724, 8982910635457246180, -1228260466727841004, -8870629066952254909, -526008540797435088, -5031238755845142021, -8363050244592607033, 1050601700640744024, -9104611786673170314, -4479945644147199241, -6823419782998328301, -6797181997798727850, 5481659148496729987, -8215699248520360452, -517420190806294229, 3787637764983639252, 2805777124248862676, 847375026463710908, -752806257333244860, -5802733257867073965, -6973496662755627239, 3473454836096478605, 5913384000201698403, -5389236760772073822, -8414280654740947122, 3781334199812295253, 7106186427969879811, -5793392653945612514, 4025496630557953873, 2029509328065975744, 7572757562784032698, -2409285778846785268, 8978472449360675819, 1502576153090782858, -524754924171314294, -5430506207796491830, -3681655679894962053, 5884494403462724943, 7057525460429085795, 6045128197566372326, 3068439635150742873, 5459483613324200529, -1099342907611602685, -8333623299114170297, 5575333565033227947, -8354986150955517165, 8957282480649403114, -4820459891421864876, 6809654053429862128, 4545870922630195580, 7197311542935486176, -2224608079234315120, -2141755264538606024, 2567830060494624486, -6270558622819592064, -4631885184728004763, 5954771488972332706, 7426073577700947604, 9036595665094295454, -549019315323478217, -7605262589627026961, 7538503311332390280, 5243496430380841675, -5125800136257737648, -189067622801948902, 6609318324048658940, -6407003720857192075, 6821243825376985989, -8663409582093444260, -8403726365964456251, -6966940567562465809, 2209597621040018613, -785009207590992232, 7148233497746128406, 8290593398169627427, -1934557347998048138, -1747811994016572301, -5360972975488153447, -4344532326911873111, -2181569417592666651, -5367930324551905863, -7161819751367151648]
```

What am I missing? Isn't it enough to specify initial_token and restart the cassandra?

I can't avoid random generation of initial_token by cassandra, because cassandra is automatically started after installation, i.e. even before I can edit cassandra.yaml for initial_token specification.

I am using cassandra 3.7.

I am using the same step to retrieve initial token from source node and then to verify on target node.

```
$ nodetool ring | grep ip_address_of_node | awk '{print $NF ","}' | xargs
```

Edit: Adding more investigation details ...

I clear the system table data from the node and restart cassandra. But cassandra still picks auto-generated tokens and not those initial_tokens mentioned in cassandra.yml. This clearly violates step 4 of procedure mentioned in official documentation.

So I can rephrase my question as follows:
System tables are removed. It's not picking from cassandra.yml. Then where from cassandra picks intial_tokens after restart?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved what I want i.e. make Cassandra to pick initial tokens provided by me.

I ensured that the cassandra.yaml contains the desired "initial_tokens" value mentioned right from the beginning. So this way, Cassandra does not auto-generate tokens and just picks provided initial_tokens, the very first time it is started.

Comment: This still does not tell what's wrong with official documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The initial_token should only be set when not using vnodes. It also should only be one token. When using vnodes the tokens will be automatically distributed when bootstraping a node and it will ignorde this setting.

Comment: My source cluster is not a cluster with single-token nodes. 

Source as well as target nodes num_tokens: 256. Isn't I am using vnodes?

Comment: num_tokens: Defines the number of tokens randomly assigned to this node on the ring when using virtual nodes (vnodes). So yes, you are using vnodes. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#configCassandra_yaml_r__num_tokens

Comment: The example given in the official documentation uses multiple tokens set as value for initial_token. So I am quite confident that initial_token can be set when using vnodes; atleast in cassandra 3.0.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I just looked at the code and tested it myself. For me it works to set the initial_token and num_tokens together. This is where it goes wrong for you: if (initialTokens.size() < 1). For some reason the initial_token option doesn't seem to work for you, which is very strange since it's ouputted in Node configuration log

Comment: Actually I just noticed that your log entries for Node configuration and generated tokens are very different times. They are more than 3 hours apart so they cannot be the same startup. The latest of them is the node configuration. Are you sure the tokens are not correct?

Comment: Those are correct. I tried restarting cassandra again and again. Every time I was getting same log. This, one of those logs, just happens to be after 3 hour.